# How to replace tokens found in files via Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I use Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) for most of my software deployments. TFS allows me to dynamically replace text within specific configuration files during the release process to specific environments (dev, test, prod).

The text it replaces are placeholders called "tokens". For instance, during my automated deployments, TFS will allow us to replace tokens found within configuration files with pre-defined values saved in the build administration for each environment. This way, I don't store any real credentials in source control for any environment. I also don't store any script in source that would hold these sensative credentials. The credentials are dynamically inserted over top the tokens during the release, and the credentials are hosted/saved/configured inside of the release system (not in a script).

For example, I have a configuration file (web.config) that has tokens.  A token looks something like this:

```
MySettingName=${MYSETTINGVALUE}
```

During the release to DEV, I want the text ${MYSETTINGVALUE} replaced with the word TEN.  During the release to PROD, I want that same ${MYSETTINGVALUE} text replaced with the word ORANGE.  And I want to store those two values (TEN and ORANGE) in the release administration system, and not in a script.

**How do I configure Jenkins to do this same thing?**

I have searched up-and-down for this specific answer.  While many blogs, articles, documentation exist, none of them speak directly to this issue.

- I would prefer NOT to use some additional 3rd party software to do
  this.
- I would prefer NOT to kick off some manual build and supply these
  values each and every time.
- I would also prefer NOT to use an Operating System level system
  variable (aka evironment variable).  In case that server dies, I
  would rather not have to remember to setup those OS environment
  varialbles on the next server.

Comment: For clarification: You want the values for those tokes stored somewhere in Jenkins at a secure location? Do you need to replace those tokens in a way that the file will be patched and saved to the disk or that you read those tokens to memory and have the values only available as - let's say - paramters to your script?

Comment: @JoergS Yes. I would prefer to store the values for those tokens in Jenkins. I do need to replace the tokens on the file/disk per environment being deployed to. The app will read the values out of the file and use that in memory.

Comment: Did you already try the credentials plugin mentioned below?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins has a built-in credentials plugin for handling secrets in builds.
See this article on how to use them:  https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci/latest/cloud-secure-guide/injecting-secrets

Basically it stores credentials securely and injects them into your jobs as variables which can then be used like any other.